# Magento 2: load product by product id or product sku

Tags: magento2

I need to load product by product id or product sku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{   
    protected $_productRepository;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    }

    public function getProductBySku($sku)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
    }
}
?>
```

In Phtml file:

```
$id = YOUR_PRODUCT_ID;
$sku = 'YOUR_PRODUCT_SKU';
$_product = $block->getProductById($id);
$_product = $block->getProductBySku($sku);
echo $_product->getEntityId();
echo '<br />';
echo $_product->getName();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying the answer.